# v.voronoi issue

Tags: grass-gis

I'm trying to use `grass7:v.voronoi` algorithm, but it seems that it doesn't process all the points....

At the bottom of this, two points are in the same area whereas there should be 2 areas...

Is there an issue with this algorithm ?
[image]